# Meaningless error report when importing multi-value custom fields

Tags: import, multi-record

I'm trying to import some multi-value custom field and I am getting what is clearly a badly formed error message. I've eliminated most of my errors by careful perusal of my import data and correcting a couple of typos. But I can't find the last one.

It gives me a link to an error CSV to export (like normal contact import) but it contains what looks like code to me. This is what it gives me in 2x6 cells of the CSV. There is also a bit of html showing as text (line break and "warning" in bold, but I can't workout how to show these in SE)

```
                  
Warning:  Declaration of CRM_Custom_Import_Parser::run($fileName  $separator  &$mapper    $skipColumnHeader = false
```

What does this mean???

Note that the documentation calls it multi-value, but the tag I have found is multi-record which describes it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the custom import inherits some code from the contact import, but in a way that isn't strictly valid (the parameters for the run() method are different than the parent). It would need fixing in core, and looks non-trivial, but it's a warning so the import should still run. Does it still run properly?

Comment: Thanks - I eventually found what was my last error by continually cutting the import file in half until I found the bad entry. But it was an error not just a warning as CiviCRM  said it would skip that line of the import file.Thanks for confirmation that this is a bug and I should report it.

Comment: I did a test in the demo site and I got the proper error message there so it must have been fixed though I can't see anything in the release notes. I am using 5.11.0. I will test again when I have the opportunity to upgrade my site.